# How to become a TOR node

Tags: proxy, node

I'm very uneducated about this so pardon me if I'm using the wrong words. I saw on Twitter that one can make their computer into a "proxy" or "node" to facilitate the Tor network to help Iranian protestors gain access to the internet.
Can someone please explain to me how?

Comment: There are different types of Tor nodes (also called Tor relays), but the type you would probably want to run is a ["Tor bridge"](https://blog.torproject.org/run-tor-bridges-defend-open-internet/).

Comment: @Steve thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

There're multiple roles in a Tor network, and I suggest you to start as a regular node with a Directory mirror. All you have to ensure for that is just two ports opened - for the relay and for the directory mirror. If you need further instructions - just drop me a line!